# Invert Return Value of Type IO Bool

Tags: haskell, boolean, monads, functor

I have a function that returns the type `IO Bool`. I'd like to use this function as an argument to `filterM`, but what I actually want to do is to invert its output. I've tried something to the effect of `(not . f)`, but `not` isn't hip to the `IO` vibe. How can I invert an `IO Bool`?

Here's a minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
module Main where
import Prelude.Unicode

userEnteredStr ∷ String → IO Bool
userEnteredStr str = do
    input ← getLine
    return (input ≡ str)

-- doesn't work. How would I write this function? 
--userDidntEnterStr ∷ String → IO Bool
--userDidntEnterStr str = not . userEnteredStr

main = do result ← userEnteredStr "y"
          print result
```

Sorry if this is basic! I can't find a function on Hoogle with type `IO Bool -> IO Bool` and haven't found anything in my web searching.

Comment: Try hoogling for `(Bool -> Bool) -> (IO Bool -> IO Bool)` instead. It gets the right answer eventually... quite low in the list, I grant you, but it does get it. `(a -> b) -> (IO a -> IO b)` gets it at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record, "doesn't work" is not a very helpful error description :)  Is it a syntax error?  a type error?  does it compile and typecheck, but return the wrong value?  It's probably the most vague description of your problem possible...and is usually a really really big impairment/hurdle for anyone who wants to help you.

The main problem here is that you can't apply `not` to an `IO Bool`, because `not` only works on `Bool`s.  An `IO Bool` is not a `Bool`, nor does it "contain a `Bool`", so it's not surprising that it doesn't work.  It's like trying to apply `(* 2)` to your dog.  Your dog isn't a number!

But it seems like you know how to work with do notation and binding from IO, so maybe you can understand why this would work?

```
userDidntEnterStr :: String -> IO Bool
userDidntEnterStr str = do
   didEnter <- userEnteredStr str
   return (not didEnter)
```

Alternatively, you can also apply any `(a -> b)` to the *result* of an `IO a` to get a new `IO b` using `fmap`:

```
userDidntEnterStr :: String -> IO Bool
userDidntEnterStr str = fmap not (userEnteredStr str)
```

Comment: Fair comment, not including the compiler output was a rookie mistake. Thanks for the great answer, I think `fmap` is exactly what I was looking for!